# How can I skip active record validations in some special cases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I am having a RoR application for human resource planning. Normaly it is not allowed to delete entries from the past. From time to time I have to delete users and of course I want to delete all entries.

My user model:

```
has_many :team_memberships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :slots, through: :team_memberships, source: :slot
```

TeamMembership model:

```
before_destroy :check_permission
def check_permission
  if self.slot.start_time < Time.now.beginning_of_day
    errors.add(:base, "Historische Einträge können nicht gelöscht werden")
    return false
   end
end
```

A rake task just destroys the old users, but that does not work, when they have historical entries.

How can I skip the before_destroy validation when User.destroy is called by a rake task?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a new method to your model that set a variable and use that as a return value of the callback:

```
before_destroy :check_permission

def allow_deletion!
  @allow_deletion = true
end

def check_permission
  if !@allow_deletion && self.slot.start_time < Time.now.beginning_of_day
    errors.add(:base, "Historische Einträge können nicht gelöscht werden")
    return false
  end
end
```

That allows you to write something like this:

```
user.allow_deletion!
user.destroy
```

This method has the benefit over `delete` that you only skip this specific callback and not all callbacks and dependent destroy operations.

Comment: That was the idea, I was looking for! THX

Answer (score 0):

You can call `user.delete` which will skip the callbacks.

Comment: In this situation though it will note destroy the associated `team_memberships` association